# nextjs firebaseauth redirect before render page if logged in

Tags: javascript, firebase-authentication, next.js

I have a login page and an auth provider as follow

```js
import * as yup from "yup";

import { useState } from 'react'

import { AuthErrorCodes } from 'firebase/auth'
import Cover from '../../components/Cover'
import Head from 'next/head'
import Headingblock from '../../components/Headingblock'
import Section from '../../components/Section'
import { authErrorCodesTranslation } from '../../config/firebase';
import { siteTitle } from '../_app'
import { useForm } from 'react-hook-form';
import { yupResolver } from '@hookform/resolvers/yup';
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';
import { useAuth } from "../../contexts/auth";
import { auth } from '../../config/firebase';
import { signInWithEmailAndPassword } from "firebase/auth";
import {useEffect} from 'react'

export default function Login() {

  const [response, setResponse] = useState({});
  const [user, userLoading] = useAuth();
  const router = useRouter();

  console.log(userLoading);

  if (!userLoading && user)
    router.push('/');

  const schema = yup.object().shape({
    email: yup.string().email('Adresse email invalide').required('Veuillez renseigner votre adresse email.'),
    password: yup.string().required('Veuillez renseigner votre mot de passe')
  });

  const { register, handleSubmit, formState } = useForm({
    resolver: yupResolver(schema),
  });

  const { errors } = formState;
  

  const onSubmit = async (data) => {
    
    await signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, data.email, data.password)
        .then(userCredential => {
          router.push("/profile");
        }).catch(error => {
            const authErrorCode = Object.keys(AuthErrorCodes).find(k => AuthErrorCodes[k] === error.message);

            let errorTranslation = authErrorCodesTranslation.GLOBAL_AUTH_ERROR;

            if (authErrorCode !== undefined)
              errorTranslation = authErrorCodesTranslation[authErrorCode];

            setResponse({ status: 'error', message: errorTranslation });
        })
  }

  return (
    <>
      <Head>
        <title>{siteTitle} - Connexion</title>
      </Head>

      <Cover />

      <Section>
        <div className='container marginNTop100'>
          <div style={{ padding: '3rem 1.5rem', background: 'white', boxShadow: '0 30px 50px 0 rgb(1 1 1 / 15%)' }}>
            <Headingblock main="Connexion" />
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
              <div className="form-row">
                <div className="form-group col" style={formgroupStyle}>
                  <label style={labelStyle}>Adresse email</label>
                  <input {...register("email")} type="text" className='form-control' style={formcontrolStyle} />
                  <div className="invalid-feedback" style={invalidStyle}>{errors.email?.message}</div>
                </div>
                <div className="form-group col" style={formgroupStyle}>
                  <label style={labelStyle}>Mot de passe</label>
                  <input {...register("password")} type="password" className='form-control' style={formcontrolStyle} />
                  <div className="invalid-feedback" style={invalidStyle}>{errors.password?.message}</div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div className="form-group" style={formgroupStyle}>
                <button type="submit" style={Object.assign(btnStyle, btnprimaryStyle)}>
                  Connexion
                </button>
              </div>
              {
                response.status === 'error' && <div style={Object.assign(alertStyle, alertDangerStyle)}>{response.message}</div>
              }
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </Section>
    </>
  )
}
```

```js
import { createContext, useState, useEffect, useContext } from 'react';
import { onAuthStateChanged } from 'firebase/auth';
import { auth } from '../config/firebase'

const AuthContext = createContext({ user: null, userLoading: true });

export const AuthProvider = ({ children }) => {
    const [userLoading, setUserLoading] = useState(true);
    const [user, setUser] = useState();

    useEffect(() => {
        
        return onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {
            
            console.log('autstatechanged');
            if (user) {
                console.log("1");
                setUser(user);
                setUserLoading(false);
                // ...
            } else {
                console.log("2");
                setUser(null);
            }
        });
    }, []);

    return (
        <AuthContext.Provider value={[user, userLoading]}>
            {children}
        </AuthContext.Provider>
    );
};

export const useAuth = () => useContext(AuthContext);
```

Once user is logged in I would like that page being not available anymore so I made a redirect once `user` is set and `userloading` is false but the page is rendering before redirect that causes a blink effect.

I wouldn't like return a loading screen I think It should be possible to not render login page if user is logged in